# Import DXA publication into SDL Tridion Sites 9

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, sites-9, dxa2.2

I've downloaded the latest DXA .Net version 2.2 and now would like to try importing DXA publications into SDL Tridion Sites Content Manager. But as per SDL document, the CM should not contain publications with the following names: 000 Empty, 100 Master, 110 DXASite Type, 200 Example Content, or 400 Example Site. 
But in our case, we do have few publications with the same name already (000 Empty and 100 Master publication we already have). 
Please suggest we need to follow a different approach to import.

Answer (score 7):

You can

- rename your existing publications,
- perform the install and then
- *bearing in mind you will need to account for Blueprinting*, you can integrate the contents of organizational items as best suits your needs.

I just got reminded I had some problems with this a while back, have a glance here too: [TRI Import.ps1 fails for websites-only](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11732/tri-import-ps1-fails-for-websites-only)

Also, Bart had some useful information on using the `master-only` setting here: [Error while importing all publications of DXA into SDL Web 8(running cms-import.ps1)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16089/error-while-importing-all-publications-of-dxa-into-sdl-web-8running-cms-import/16090#16090)

Answer (score 4):

The `cms-import.ps1` script has parameters for dealing with this problem. There's a very good reason why a script is provided to deal with the import rather than a compiled programme: you can read the script yourself. So for example at line 81, you can see how they use the parameters to create a base webdav URL.

```
$WebDavUrl = "/webdav/$masterPublication/$rootFolder/Framework/Developer/Templates"
```

So by inspecting the script, and combining that information with your own knowledge of how things are laid out in your Tridion system, you can just pass the appropriate parameters. Something like this:

```
cms-import.ps1 -importType master-only -masterPublication"456 Master" -rootFolder "Rooty Tooty"
```

The script is plainly intended to be read by implementers. There are some useful comments in there too. If you go through it carefully, you should be able to figure out just how it should be used in your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed use `-importType master-only`, but this is intended for importing DXA Core Items (excl. the Example Site) into an existing BluePrint (or upgrading).

If you want to import the entire DXA BluePrint (incl. example Publications) into a system which happens to already have Publications with same names, but you don’t want to import into that existing BluePrint, then your only option is to (temporarily) rename the existing, conflicting Publications.